# Heroku Dashboard bug

Tags: heroku, dashboard, adblock

Is anyone else having this issue with Heroku?

`Something went wrong. If you're using an ad-blocker, please try disabling it. You can also check the Heroku Status site to see if there are any incidents impacting our service.`

And in the top corner shows `Unknown error`

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq8ca.png)

I was using my dashboard normally until 2 days ago, then I started getting this splash and even disabling my adblocker this still remains. And in Firefox I get an eternal loading page (after authentication).

I'm pretty new using Heroku, but it seems that a free user just can't create a ticket or email them anyway... LOL

I'm being able to do what I need through terminal/cmd by now, but eventually a dashboard would be great!

Comment: They are having outage: https://status.heroku.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the site is experiencing some sort of problem. It is the website itself and not you.
You can check in Status to see if there is a real problem reporting (but if the problem just happened, it may not happen so quickly)

I suggest that if you really have a question, you write an email to ask.

> outage-support@heroku.com

Their reply is very fast (my experience is that they reply after 2 minutes), here is their reply

> We're seeing similar reports and looking into this, possibly an incident brewing. We should have a status post shortly: https://status.heroku.com/.

Comment: ps.: They never answered me
I just moved to `render.com` and all my problems are gone lol